# Does the password get sent in the clear when connecting to Sql-Server?

Tags: sql-server, security, connection-strings

I was asked this today and I honestly did not know the answer. If you connect using a connection string without sspi to a server is there any way a 3rd party can intercept ***on the wire*** the password used to log in?

```
"Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User Id=sa;Password=CanThisBeSniffed;"
```

I am not asking about MiTM attacks just someone listing on the same computer or on the same hub on the network with wireshark or something similar running.

I fired up wireshark myself and did not see it in plain text but it could be a simple obfuscation or proper encryption, I just wanted to know which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2000 and up (might be 2005 and up, I forget; it's in my new book somewhere) the authentication process used by a SQL Authentication Login (as opposed to Windows Authentication) is encrypted by a self signed SSL certificate which is generated by the SQL Server instance on install of the database engine.

Answer (score 4):

Nick raises a good point, being that blog post wasn't exactly what you were after. Sorry about that.

The MSDN library has specifics about configuring SSL connections http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx

However, the following is slightly ambiguous

```
Credentials (in the login packet) that are transmitted when a client application 
connects to SQL Server are always encrypted.
```

It's not entirely clear (to me anyway) if that means they are always encrypted irrespective of the SSL settings, or not.

If you are concerned about it, I would be enabling SSL.

Comment: that blog post is about how sql server stores passwords, not how a client authenticates with a server across a network

Answer (score 2):

I've been doing some digging on this too, and there is a possible MITM attack to force a downgrade - see [here](http://f0rki.at/microsoft-sql-server-downgrade-attack.html)

Some older versions of SQL don't support SSL-encrypting the login, and send the password in the clear, so both client and server support fall-back to unencrypted authentication if the encrypted auth fails.  But you can't set modern versions of SQL Server to ENCRYPT_NOT_SUP on purpose (note that the attack is to MITM the PRELOGIN session and alter a flag to ENCRYPT_NOT_SUP instead of ENCRYPT_OFF - which is the default mode for SQL).